# Bad cursor spec error after a simple tkinter.Tk() in python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am running python 3.6.2 on a Manjaro i3wm Linux install.

I have installed the last version of `tk` and `tcl` (8.6), however when executing these simple lines in Python:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> root = tkinter.Tk()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2017, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: bad cursor spec "#EAD49B"
```

Hence I cannot use `tkinter` at all on my current install, which seems perfectly standard, and I have no clue what to do.

Any ideas ?

Comment: do you have a file named `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources` in your home directory?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: No I have no such file in my home directory

Comment: The default cursor is not passed but is coded in _tkinter.c.  Whoever compiled it either left a default Linux value, probably for X, that is not valid for 8.6 on `i3` or changed it badly.  They apparently neglected to even run the elementary test you did, let alone run the Python test suite with `-ugui`.  I would inform whoever you got the 3.6 tkinter from.

Comment: Well it seems that it was part of the default python install that is provided in the Arch extra repository

Comment: @BryanOakley : I was wrong, i do have a `.Xresources` file in my home directory

Comment: you should search that file to see if any line contains the string `#EAD49B".

Comment: @BryanOakley Nice ! There was indeed a `*cursor: #EAD49B` line in my .extend.Xresources file which is included in .Xresources. I commented it and everything is now working like a charm ! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by Brian Oakley in the comments above, the issue was coming from my `.Xresources` files in the home directory, which contained a line :

```
*cursor: #EAD49B
```

Commenting this line solved the issue